# Linq 'Unable to process the type 'Anonymous type', because it has no known mapping to the value layer.' in MVC

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert a SQL Command to Linq but gets the error *'Unable to process the type 'Anonymous type', because it has no known mapping to the value layer.'*

**SQL Code**

```
SELECT ooe.id, parts.title, appro.totalAppro, allo.TotalAllotment, cost.total_cost, (CASE WHEN cost.total_cost IS NULL THEN (SELECT allo.TotalAllotment) ELSE (SELECT allo.TotalAllotment - cost.total_cost) END) AS unobligated 
FROM pmTA_OoeGeneral AS ooe INNER JOIN 
     pmTA_Particulars AS parts ON ooe.particular_id = parts.id LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     pmTA_vwObligationRequestDetailsTotalCostByOoe AS cost ON ooe.id = cost.ooe_general_id 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN pmTA_vwTotalAllotmentGeneralFund AS allo ON ooe.id = allo.ooe_general_id 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN pmTA_vwTotalAppropriationGeneralFund AS appro ON ooe.id = appro.ooe_general_id 
WHERE (ooe.year = @year) AND (ooe.project_category_id = @cat) and (ooe.type = @type) order by ooe.id
```

**LINQ Code**

```
    var gvStatusGenOffices = (from a in db.iBudget_OoeGeneral 
                             join b in db.iBudget_Particulars on a.ParticularID equals b.id
                             join c in obligationRequestDetailsTotalCostByOoe on a.id equals c.id
                             join d in totalAllotmentGeneralFund on a.id equals d.id
                             join e in totalAppropriationGeneralFund on a.id equals e.id
                             where a.YearID==year && a.ProjectID==cat && a.type==type
                             orderby a.id
                             select new
                             {
                                 id = a.id,
                                 title = b.title,
                                 appro = e.totalAppro,
                                 allo = d.totalAllo,
                                 cost = c.totalCost,
                                 unobligated = c.totalCost==null ? d.totalAllo : d.totalAllo - c.totalCost
                             }).ToList();
```

**db.iBudget_OoeGeneral** and **db.iBudget_Particulars** are model class in my project

**obligationRequestDetailsTotalCostByOoe** , **totalAllotmentGeneralFund** and **totalAppropriationGeneralFund** are variables with list values.

The question is what is causing this error? I tried looking the web for some answers but none was showing up.

**UPDATE**

```
var obligationRequestDetailsTotalCostByOoe = (from p in db.iBudget_ObligationRequestDetails
                                 where p.ooe_general_id != null && p.is_approved == 1
                                 group p by p.ooe_general_id into g
                                 select g)
                                 .AsEnumerable() 
                                 .Select(g => new {
                                     id = g.Key,
                                     totalCost = g.Sum(p => Convert.ToDouble(p.amount))
                                  }).ToList();
```

Originally, **obligationRequestDetailsTotalCostByOoe** , **totalAllotmentGeneralFund** and **totalAppropriationGeneralFund** were Views in SQL Server. Since I was practicing how to code Linq, I didn't create a View and just made a var with list same with the original View Code in SQL.

Comment: Can you show how are you creating e.g. `obligationRequestDetailsTotalCostByOoe `?

Comment: Is `db.iBudget_OoeGeneral` and `obligationRequestDetailsTotalCostByOne` in the same context ?

Comment: @arekzyla I have included the code for obligationRequestDetailsTotalCostByOoe . As you can see, this code is only a variable with stored data

Comment: @Florian db.iBudget_OoeGeneral is taken from the model while the  obligationRequestDetailsTotalCostByOoe is a var for the linq code I made